# ola estou com dificuldade em saber vincular uma pergunta com uma resposta de 2 listas separadas (uma lista de perguntas e uma de respostas):

Tags: python

Preciso fazer um programa similar ao aplicativo "Anki", onde a pessoa vai colocar uma palavra em inglês e logo depois sua tradução.

O programa deve ler todas as perguntas e escolher uma aleatoriamente para ser devolvida ao usuário, a pessoa deve responder e o programa deve dizer se está certo ou errado. Se estiver errado ele deve devolver a resposta correta.

O problema é que não consigo vincular a pergunta com a resposta certa para assim poder fazer o programa ler se esta certo ou não. Gostaria de uma ajuda para isso.

Segue o que fiz até agora:

```
import random
R = []
P = []
i = 0
num = int(input("informe quantas cartas serão digitadas:"))
for i in range(num):
    p = str(input("digite a palavra número {0}".format(i+1)))
    r = str(input("digite a resposta número {0}".format(i+1)))
    i = i + 1
    P.append(p)
    R.append(r)
print("serão sorteadas as cartas digitadas no bloco de notas e você deverá colocar a tradução")
print("para iniciar aperte a tecla ENTER")
input()
print(random.choice(P))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pensei em um jeito bastante simples de suprir seus requisitos.
Dê uma olhada sobre dicionários em Python, são muito utilizados e são bastante versáteis.
Refatorei seu código e cheguei a uma conclusão que funcionou perfeitamente:

```
import random

cartas = dict()
i = 0
num = int(input("informe quantas cartas serão digitadas:"))
for i in range(num):
    p = str(input("digite a palavra número {0}: ".format(i+1)))
    r = str(input("digite a resposta número {0}: ".format(i+1)))
    cartas[p] = r

print("serão sorteadas as cartas digitadas no bloco de notas e você deverá colocar a tradução")
print("para iniciar aperte a tecla ENTER")
input()

carta_da_vez = random.choice(list(cartas))
print(carta_da_vez)
traducao = input("Qual a tradução da palavra acima?\n")
if traducao == cartas[carta_da_vez]:
    print("Parabéns! Você acertou!")
else:
    print(f"Que pena, a resposta certa era: {cartas[carta_da_vez]}!")
```

Perceba que dentro do `for`, depois de lidas as perguntas e respostas, uma chave é criada no dicionário **cartas**, sendo essa chave a palavra, e para essa chave é designado um valor, que seria a resposta.

Vale a pena lembrar que o `for` no Python percorre os elementos de uma estrutura de dados, não apenas incrementa uma variável. Portanto, não é necessário o `i = i + 1`.

No final, uma palavra é escolhida pelo `random.choice()`. Por esta palavra ser a chave de um dicionário, temos acesso ao valor dela. A verificação é feita através do valor da chave sorteada.

Segue link para documentação acerca de dicionários:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: olá, cara me ajudou mto, mto obrigado !

Comment: Que maravilha! Tamo junto.

Answer (score 4):

Como a pergunta e a resposta estão em listas separadas, ao sortear uma pergunta fica difícil achar a resposta correspondente. Existem várias formas, vou citar algumas:

- Ao invés de usar `random.choice()` para sortear uma pergunta, use `random.randrange()` para sortear um índice numérico - assim você pode usá-lo nas duas listas:

  ```
   idx = random.randrange(len(P))
   pergunta = P[idx]
   resposta = R[idx]
  ```
- Uma idéia que me parece mais limpa seria usar apenas uma lista - Coloque a pergunta e resposta no mesmo item da mesma lista:

  ```
   P.append((p, r))
  ```

  ... em seguida, `random.choice()` devolveria os dois ao mesmo tempo:

  ```
   pergunta, resposta = random.choice(P)
  ```

Comment: certo irei utilizar, valeu pela ajuda !